# Numpy TypeError must be integer, not tuple

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy, matplotlib

I want to create a model using logistic regression. For this reason first i take the data from the [file](http://archive.ics.uci.edu/ml/machine-learning-databases/undocumented/connectionist-bench/sonar/sonar.all-data) and separate each line from this txt and split it according to "," and put them into my array (datum). After that i converted that array to numPy array and shuffle it randomly. But when i slice array into two different piece for testing and training.

This error occured:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File ".\logisticRegression.py", line 32, in <module>
    training_data = matrix_data[167:,:]
TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not tuple
```

Here is the code that i wrote:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt


def load_data(path):
    datum= []
    with open(path) as fp:
        line = fp.readline()
        while line:
            arr_line= line.split(",")
            datum.append(arr_line)
            line=fp.readline()
    return datum

#Sigmoid function
def sigmoid(x):
    return 1/(1+np.exp(-x))

#Loss function
def square_loss(y_pred, target):
    return np.mean(pow(((y_pred - target),2)))

if __name__ == "__main__":
    # load the data from the file
    matrix_data = load_data("all_data.txt")
    np.array(matrix_data)

    np.random.shuffle(matrix_data)

    training_data = matrix_data[167:,:] #These all lines gives error
    test_data = matrix_data[41:,:] #These all lines gives error

    X_tr, y_tr = training_data[:, :-1], training_data[:, -1] #These all lines gives error
    X_te, y_te = test_data[:, :-1], test_data[:, -1] #These all lines gives error
```

Note: I searched for this error and i found that the problem is the lack of comma in my array but when i print the array it has comma for each index.

Comment: `np.array(matrix_data)` What do you expect that line to do?  You're calling `np.array()` but you're not saving the result into a new variable...

Comment: `matrix_data` is a `list`.

Comment: As an aside, use the `csv` module. At the very least, stop with the `while line` stuff, file objects *are iterable*. All you need is `for line in open(path): ...`

Answer (score 2):

You have to assign the result of np.array to a variable, it doesn't change the argument matrix_data:

```
matrix_data = np.array(matrix_data)
```

Your code failes because you still have a list and not a numpy datastructure.

Comment: Thanks, i can't believe that is the problem :) . It escaped me.